# Proving that the group $U(30)$ is isomorphic to the group $\Bbb Z_8$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups, group-isomorphism

I am trying to prove that the group $U(30)$ is isomorphic to the group $\Bbb Z_8$.

I know that both groups have an order of $8$ and are both cyclic, but this isn't enough to show that an isomorphism exists between the two.

To show an isomorphism exists between two groups I need to show that there exists a bijection between them and that $F(xy) = F(x)*F(y)$, however, I don't have a physical function to work with.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What do you know about cyclic groups? What do they have that other groups don't?

Comment: @Arthur thank you, I figured it out now. Since U30 is cyclic and has a finite order of 8 it must be isomorphic to Z8.

Comment: Since $30=6\times5$, isn't $U(30)$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$? So they are not isomorphic

Comment: By Fermat's theorem applied to $p=2,3,5$, we have $x^4 \equiv 1 \bmod 8$ for all $x \in U(30)$. Since $U(30)$ has order $8$, it cannot be cyclic.

Comment: @lhf $\pmod{30}$

Comment: @Evariste, yes, sorry fo the typo.

Answer (score 3):

Since

$$30=2\times 3\times 5$$

is the prime factorization of $30$ and hence $U_{30}$ is isomorphic to $ U_2\times U_3\times U_5$ which is $\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_4$ and hence the given group is not cyclic.